# xdebug not working with vagrant drupal development VDD virtual machine VM

Tags: drupal-7, virtual-machine, vagrant, xdebug

I have installed vdd

```
 https://www.drupal.org/node/2008792
```

then tried and make xdebug working with phpstorms IDE ( or eclipse )

```
 https://www.drupal.org/node/2146223
```

xdebug is not working in my vagrant VM while it is working fine on a local wamp project.

what could be the reason and how can i pinpoint the problem?

xdebug supposed to be working out of the box in vdd.
Is there something specific to set for remote xdebug?
Apparently xdebug connectback should find the remote adress fine and xdebug chrome helper should set a cookie fine.

here is my VM xdebug config:

```
 xdebug.remote_connect_back =1
xdebug.default_enable = 1
 xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
 xdebug.remote_port = 9000
 xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
  xdebug.remote_host=192.168.44.44
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the very same problem here with latest Drupal vagrant and xdebug in Sublime Text 3.
Would be very happy to find a solution.

EDIT:
After digging a little deeper I found [in the xdebug docs](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#remote_host) that the setting xdebug.remote_host has to be the IP of the client on which the IDE is running. You currently have the vdd box IP there.
But this setting is being ignored when xdebug.remote_connect_back is enabled, which it is in your case.

Anyways, haven't been able to get it running yet...

Comment: yes i have put xdebug.remote_connect_back =1 not to be bothered about ip. ihave not solved it yet either